# Action to return either Result or Promise<Result>

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

Is there a way to have an `Action` which can return either a `Result` or a `Promise<Result>`?

The scenario is that based on the request (parameters and headers) the action decides if to return a simple `Result` or it needs to make a http request to another service and only then return the result, and so to use `Promise<Result>`.

routes:

```
GET /dosomething    controllers.MyController.doSomething()
```

java:

```
public static Result doSomething() {
    Request request = request();

    if (...) {
        return getData();
    } else {
        return ok(...);
    }
}

private static Promise<Result> getData() {
    ...
}
```

The problem is that if the `Action` returns one (in it's signature) then I can't return the other...

Any ideas on how to go about this?

Comment: The easiest would be to always return a Promise, and wrap non-async actions with a completed Promise.

Comment: Can't say I like this solution but it works. Thanks a lot! I added it as an answer with some code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, the easiest would be to always return a Promise, and wrap non-async actions with a completed Promise. To wrap a value in a completed promise, simply use the static `pure` method:

```
public static Promise<Result> doSomethingAsync() {
  if (...) {
    return getData();
  } else {
    return F.Promise.pure(ok(...));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is far from being an optimal solution but it seems to do the trick, and I'm adding it as an answer in case others will look for a solution in the future.
If you have another idea of how to handle this situation I'd love to know!

Based on the advise made by @MariusSoutier I created this method:

```
public static F.Promise<Result> wrapResultAsPromise(final Result result) {
    return F.Promise.promise(
        new F.Function0<Result>() {
            public Result apply() {
                return result;
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Then if an `Action` has a scenario for which it needs to return a promise then all returned results are wrapped up as promises.